# Javascript not working on Js loaded table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using sheetstotables which uses Javascript to turn Google Spreadsheet tables into HTML tables. Used a nifty highlight script so I can highlight keywords. It worked when I was using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhLQ7/13/) to test out the script when the tables were raw HTML. However, the same script doesn't seem to work on the table that is loaded through Javascript which can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2yLcsw0/46/)

Code (working) HTML

```
    <input id = "search" type ="text" value = "cy">
<div class = "searchable"><table>
  <tr>
    <th>cy</th>
    <th>cy</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table></div>
```

Javascript

```
if($('#search').val().length !== 0){
   $('td').each(function(){
   var search_value = $("#search").val();
   var search_regexp = new RegExp(search_value, "g");
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(search_regexp,"<a class = 'highlight'>"+search_value+"</a>"));
 });
 }
```

Css

```
.highlight {
             font-weight:bold;
             color:green;
             display: block;
             background: #000;
}
```

Code (not working) HTML

```
<input id = "search" type ="text" value = "GK">

<div class="sheetstotables"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableId = "m4CB4"
var x = document.createElement("script"); x.type = "text/javascript"; x.async = true;
x.src = "http://www.sheetstotables.com/get_table.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(x, s);
</script>
```

Javascript

```
if($('#search').val().length !== 0){
   $('td').each(function(){
   var search_value = $("#search").val();
   var search_regexp = new RegExp(search_value, "g");
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(search_regexp,"<a class = 'highlight'>"+search_value+"</a>"));
 });
 }
```

Css

```
.highlight {
             font-weight:bold;
             color:green;
             display: block;
             background: #000;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score -2):

Try the following(edited)

```
<input id = "search" type ="text" value = "GK">

<div class="sheetstotables"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableId = "m4CB4";
var x = document.createElement("script")
x.type = "text/javascript"; 
x.async = true;
x.src = "http://www.sheetstotables.com/get_table.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")     
s[0].parentNode.insertBefore(x, s);
</script>
```

I hope it helps